# How do you check email format in Apex?

Tags: apex, controller, regular-expressions

If I have a form for candidates to apply for certain jobs online, when a candidate enters his email and submits the form, I want my controller to validate the email format that was entered.

Can someone provide an example for doing that?

Thank you!

Comment: You don't ;) Don't waste life on this. Not really a salesforce question I think, maybe you should check stackoverflow... Best form of validation is to send a message with some confirmation link they'd have to click in my opinion... Check http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html for a start but  http://davidcel.is/blog/2012/09/06/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/ & http://dellsystem.me/posts/dont-do-drugs-kids/ ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unless you are masochistic*, I'd avoid regex email validation beyond the most trivial cases like `something@something`. You can read much more about this problem in StackOverflow: [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address).

As @eyescream suggests, you are better to send an actual email to that address and get confirmation back that they opened it. Not only does this confirm that it is a valid email address. It stops people signing up email addresses they don't own.

Alternatively, there are products on the AppExchange that can handle the validation for you. E.g. StrikeIron: [Live Data for SalesForce: Email Verification](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000019uHOEAY)

If you really feel like causing yourself some pain, there are example Regex in [Salesforce default Email Validation rules/specification](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Apex-Code-Development/Salesforce-default-Email-Validation-rules-specification/td-p/205057). Just remember that email addresses don't lend themselves to being validated with regex and you are likely to get false-positives.

You could also coerce an [Email Field Type](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/field_types.htm#i1435603) from an existing sObject in an apex:inputField. Salesforce have been working towards better [RFC 2822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt) support. I found [Email Address Verification](https://na1.salesforce.com/_ui/training/help/pub/UserEdSolution?id=50130000000LATo&orgId=00D000000000062), but I'm not sure how current it is.

> * Some people, when confronted with a problem, think
>   “I know, I'll use regular expressions.”
>    Now they have two problems.

Comment: The quote made me laugh. In all seriousness, email is a beast, and there's plenty of gotchas in emails that make a simple regex pointless. Is `test@io` valid? Yes. Is ` !#$%&`*+/=?^``{|}~@iana.org` valid? Sure thing. `""@asdf.com`? Yep. You bet. Avoiding RegExp is best. While you're at it, 2822 is no longer the latest spec. It's RFC 5321. Right. I didn't know about it, either.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the database chucks an error if you use an email field and the data doesn't match the format it expects... so the lazy option might be to just run an insert inside a `try  ... catch` block and see if it works or not.