# How to make regex as reusable?

Tags: apex, regular-expressions, customlabel

I have a regex which validates the user email address.I have used same regex in two controller classes.
now my code is :

```
if(!Pattern.matches ('([a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\.]+)@((\\[a-z]{1,3}\\.[a-z]{1,3}\\.[a-z]{1,3}\\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\\-]+\\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})',Email))
```

I want to avoid hard coding regex from class.
So, i had created custom label for the same regex.

**Custom label:'EmailRegex'**

I have updated controller with this custom label.

```
if(!Pattern.matches (System.label.EmailRegex,Email))
```

but however this is not working.
Actual regex is

```
"([a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\.]+)@((\\[a-z]{1,3}\\.[a-z]{1,3}\\.[a-z]{1,3}\\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\\-]+\\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})"`
```

but when am using this regex from custom label it is rendering as

```
"([a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\.]+)@((\\[a-z]{1,3}\\.[a-z]{1,3}\\.[a-z]{1,3}\\.)&#124;(([a-zA-Z0-9\\-]+\\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}&#124;[0-9]{1,3})"
```

It is replacing vertical bar(`|`) with `&#124;`.Because of this regex is not working.

Pls let me know how to do it.

Thanks,

Comment: Just my personal opinion, but please **do not** use a regular expression to validate an email address. See [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](http://stackoverflow.com/q/201323/54026)

Comment: Please also read - [How do you check email format in Apex?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/22238/102)

Comment: @Daniel isn't that pattern too long to even fit in a custom label? It's pretty absurd. And beside the point, admittedly.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Google tells me a Custom Label can go to 1000 characters. Would make for an unreadable regex. I'm just annoyed that the regex in the question won't allow for a plus sign :/

Answer (score 4):

I agree with the comments that what you are trying to attempt is not necessarily the best idea. However, in general, to fix the direct roadblock, you need to decode the label.

```
Label.MyExpression.unescapeHtml4()
```

Comment: Hi Larson,
Thanks for replay.
I tried this-->EncodingUtil.urlDecode(Label.MyExpression, 'utf-8')
but it is not working.

Comment: No.I got same output 

([a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\.]+)@((\\[a-z]{1,3}\\.[a-z]{1,3}\\.[a-z]{1,3}\\.)&#124;(([a-zA-Z0-9\\-]+\\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}&#124;[0-9]{1,3})

Comment: @Larson 
I have tried 'unescapeHtml4'. Even this is also not working.still it is showing &#124;
Thanks.

Comment: @vishnu That's pretty surprising...the following works for me in Execute Anonymous: `system.assertEquals('|', '&#124;'.unescapeHtml4());`