# Regex to find first email after specific phrase

Tags: apex, regular-expressions

I received a request to write some regex to find an email address after a specific phrase (Buyer's email address:). But, the request didn't specify that the email COULD possibly be on a newline or have multiple spaces between. Not being proficient at regex I'm here to throw myself at the feet of the regex gods. Here's what I had originally written that worked when there was just a space after the phrase followed by the email address:

```
    Pattern myPattern = Pattern.compile('Buyer\'s email address: ([\\w\\d.\\_\\%\\+\\-]+@[\\w\\d\\.\\-]+\\.[\\w]{2,4})');
    Matcher myMatcher = myPattern.matcher(emailBody);
    while(myMatcher.find()) {
        emailFrom = myMatcher.group(1).trim();
    }
```

Is there a way that I can find the first instance of an email address after the phrase "Buyer's email address:" regardless of spaces, or line-breaks, or carriage returns, or, well, anything else?

Comment: I'd assert that any god related to email regex expressions is a phony god - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/22238/102

Comment: Ha! Well, flattery never hurts when you're asking for help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I wouldn't try and solve it all in one Regex. Maybe you could, but [email regex validation will be problematic](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/22238/102).

Instead, try breaking the problem down into more manageable chunks.

The `Buyer's email address:` prefix seems like a solid starting point for an [`indexOf()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_indexOf) call. Then narrow your search to immediately after that index (and the length of the prefix). Starting from the new index, you could easily clean out any white space characters with a [`trim()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_trim). Now the email address, if present, would be the first thing at the start of the trimmed string.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I'll include my complete method for anyone who needs it in a new comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete method after I used Daniel Ballinger's suggestion above.

NOTE: In my scenario it is acceptable to return a blank string if no email address was found in the email's body text.

```
public String getFromEmailInEmailBody(String emailBody) {
            string emailFrom = '';        
            Pattern myPattern1 = Pattern.compile('Buyer\'s email address:');
            Matcher myMatcher1 = myPattern1.matcher(emailBody);
            while(myMatcher1.find()) {
                string phrase1 = myMatcher1.group(0).trim();
                integer phrase1Len = phrase1.length()+1;
                string substring = emailBody.mid(emailBody.indexOf(phrase1)+phrase1Len, emailBody.length()).trim();
                Pattern myPattern2 = Pattern.compile('([\\w\\d.\\_\\%\\+\\-]+@[\\w\\d\\.\\-]+\\.[\\w]{2,4})');
                Matcher myMatcher2 = myPattern2.matcher(substring);
                while(myMatcher2.find()){
                    emailFrom = myMatcher2.group(0).trim();
                }
            }      
            return emailFrom;       
        }
```